# How to NOT require registration during checkout in Magento?

Tags: magento, checkout

I am developing my first Magento site for a client who does not want customers to HAVE
to register / sign in during checkout. How do I make that optional?

BTW using Magento v. 1.7.0.2

Many thanks,

Cynthia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System > Configuration > Checkout > Checkout Options: Allow Guest Checkout = Yes

[image]

Comment: Ah HA! Thank you! I knew I was missing something obvious.